# Custom changelog from git log

Tags: git, shell, sed, grep, git-log

I need help to create a custom formatted change log from git log.

Here is how a git log looks like the way we write it.

```
commit 2f5719d373e284e4473a5a3f229cbf163f6385fe
Author: Adrian <adrian@mycompany.com>
Date:   Tue Nov 5 17:23:51 2013 +0100

    This is the title of the commit

    Some description about the commit, row 1
    Some description about the commit, row 2
    Some description about the commit, row 3

    ISSUE=BZ1020
    ISSUE=BZ1022        
    Change-Id: I1e15e12da28692e09c377c084dc439fec1d58f4c
```

The way I want it formatted is to extract the `title` row and `ISSUE=BZ` row and create a nice change log. I want something like this with issue number(s) first and then the title. I also want to support several `ISSUE=BZ` tags in case someone fixes several bugs in one commit. An of course, not all commits contains bug fixed so I want to omit those commits completely.

```
BZ1020 This is the title of the commit
BZ1022 This is the title of the commit
```

So far i have managed to extract all issues fixed but not the title with this command:

```
git log <old version>..HEAD | grep -i 'ISSUE=BZ' | sed 's/.*=//g'
```

Produce:

```
BZ1020
BZ1022
```

Any ideas how to proceed? I have to tell you that I am a beginner a using the `sed` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do like this:

```
git log <old version>..HEAD | awk -F= '/title/ {a=$0} /ISSUE=BZ/ {b=$2 a;gsub(/ +/," ",b);print b}'
BZ1020 This is the title of the commit
BZ1022 This is the title of the commit
```

Comment: The /title/ specifies that the row contains the word "title". The is to always grab the first row. It would be possible to use --format='format:TITLE:%s%n%b' as Robin states and create:
git log --format='format: TITLE:%s%n%b'|  awk -F= '/TITLE;/ {a=$0} /ISSUE=BZ/ {b=$2 a;gsub(/ +/," ",b);print b}' but is there a way to remove the "TITLE:" afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

The steps I would follow are:

1. Use a custom format to output just the title (with `TITLE:` prepended) and the body
2. Write a sed script that looks for `TITLE:`, stores it, then looks for `ISSUE=`, and outputs both

So here is what I've come up with in the limited time I had available. This is not exactly what you asked for, but it's a starting point:

```
git log --format='format:TITLE:%s%n%b'|sed -ne '/^TITLE:/h;s/ISSUE=//;t found;b;: found;G;p'
```